# Matlab strcat function troubles with spaces

Tags: matlab, strcat

I'm trying to accomplish this:

```
strcat('red ', 'yellow ', 'white ')
```

I expected to see "red yellow white", however, I see "redyellowwhite" on the command output. What needs to be done to ensure the spaces are concatenated properly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @#$@!#$@! another gotcha inconsistency between Matlab and C. >:(

Comment: Fast workaround: `cstrcat("he ", " l ", " lo")`, preserves the spaces.  Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14025999/445131

Comment: There are so many idiotic design decisions in Matlab, but I didn't expect something as simple as this to be a problem, too!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the matlab help page for strcat:

"strcat ignores trailing ASCII white space characters and omits all such characters from the output. White space characters in ASCII are space, newline, carriage return, tab, vertical tab, or form-feed characters, all of which return a true response from the MATLAB isspace function. Use the concatenation syntax [s1 s2 s3 ...] to preserve trailing spaces. strcat does not ignore inputs that are cell arrays of strings. "

Answer (score 24):

Although [STRCAT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/strcat.html) ignores *trailing* white space, it still preserves *leading* white space. Try this:

```
strcat('red',' yellow',' white')
```

Alternatively, you can just use the concatenation syntax:

```
['red ' 'yellow ' 'white ']
```

Answer (score 16):

In fact, you can simply use the ASCII code of space: 32. So, you can solve the problem like this:

```
str = strcat('red', 32, 'yellow', 32, 'white');
```

Then you will get `str = 'red yellow white'`.

Comment: Wow, funny that this works, even though `strcat('red', ' ', 'yellow', ' ', 'white')` removes the spaces...

Answer (score 13):

You can protect trailing whitespace in strcat() or similar functions by putting it in a cell.

```
str = strcat({'red '}, {'yellow '}, {'white '})
str = str{1}
```

Not very useful in this basic example. But if you end up doing "vectorized" operations on the strings, it's handy. Regular array concatenation doesn't do the 1-to-many concatenation that strcat does.

```
strs = strcat( {'my '}, {'red ','yellow ','white '}, 'shirt' )
```

Sticking 'my ' in a cell even though it's a single string will preserve the whitespace. Note you have to use the {} form instead of calling cellstr(), which will itself strip trailing whitespace.

This is all probably because Matlab has two forms of representing lists of strings: as a cellstr array, where all whitespace is significant, and as a blank-padded 2-dimensional char array, with each row treated as a string, and trailing whitespace ignored. The cellstr form most resembles strings in Java and C; the 2-D char form can be more memory efficient if you have many strings of similar length. Matlab's string manipulation functions are polymorphic on the two representations, and sometimes exhibit differences like this. A char literal like 'foo' is a degenerate one-string case of the 2-D char form, and Matlab's functions treat it as such.

UPDATE: As of Matlab R2019b or so, Matlab also has a new `string` array type. Double-quoted string literals make `string` arrays instead of `char` arrays. If you switch to using `string` arrays, it will solve all your problems here.

Comment: Great, that helped me when I wanted to concatenate several string cell arrays with a `' '` character: `dateTime{:} = strcat(date, {' '}, time)`

Comment: This has helped me too to preserve whitespace.  Good trick to know.  BTW, you're very close (if not already) to 1k for the MATLAB tag.  Early congratulations on getting the gold :)

Comment: Great tip. I was just looking for this.

Comment: Shameless plug: I go in to all this in more detail in this blog post: http://blog.apjanke.net/2019/04/20/matlab-string-representation-is-a-mess.html

Answer (score 2):

or you can say:

```
str = sprintf('%s%s%s', 'red ', 'yellow ', 'white ')
```