# Whitespace elliminated before numstr() in matlab

Tags: matlab

Why is it in matlab, that when you type a statement such as

```
    percentage =22
    strcat('Transfer is ', num2str(percentage), '% complete');
```

The result removes the whitespace prior to the numstr() operator... i.e

```
    ans = 'Transfer is23% complete'
```

Is there a way to prevent it from stealing my whitespace?

Comment: Duplicate of [Matlab strcat function troubles with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425226/matlab-strcat-function-troubles-with-spaces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `strcat` removes the whitespace. According to `doc strcat`:

`For character array inputs, strcat removes trailing ASCII white-space characters: space, tab, vertical tab, newline, carriage return, and form-feed.`

Solutions:

1) You may try `sprintf('Transfer is %d%% complete', percentage);`

2) Use `['Transfer is ', num2str(percentage), '% complete']` rather than `strcat` for string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
strcat({'Transfer is '}, num2str(percentage), {'% complete'});
```

Although you will end up with a singleton cell array. If you're concatenating single strings, then you should really use `[]` rather than `strcat`.

Personally, I would use `sprintf` as suggested by @grapeot.