# Octave strcat ignores added spaces

Tags: linux, octave, spaces, strcat

**Octave adds spaces with strcat**

In Octave I run these commands:

```
strcat ("hel", " ", "lo")
```

I get this result:

```
ans = hello
```

Instead of what I expected:

```
ans = hel lo
```

strcat to me sounds like "concatenate strings".  A space is a valid character, so adding a space should be OK.  Matlab has the same behaviour, so it's probably intended.

I find it counter intuitive.  Does this behavior makes sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm. It works how it is defined:

"strcat removes trailing white space in the arguments (except within cell arrays), while cstrcat leaves white space untouched. "

From http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Concatenating-Strings.html

So the question could be: Should this behaviour be changed.

Answer (score 1):

strcat takes the input parameters and trims the **trailing** spaces, but not the leading spaces.  if you pass a parameter as one or more spaces, they are collapsed to blank string.

That behavior is a manifestation of how "cellstr" works where spaces at the end are removed.

**Work around 1**

If you put the space up against the 'lo', it is a leading space and not removed.

```
strcat ("hel", " lo")

ans = hel lo
```

**Work around 2**

use cstrcat instead:

```
cstrcat("hel", " ", "lo")

ans = hel lo
```

**Work around 3**

Use sprintf, can be faster than strcat.

```
sprintf("%s%s%s\n", "hel", " ", "lo")

ans = hel lo
```